# How to use Nested Data Properties and mount methods in Vue test files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to test user input and submission using Vue test utils and jest. I'm hit with several errors and i'd be glad if someone can point me to a very good guide to TDD using Vue.

Component

```
<template>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6">
                  <label for="firstname" class="form-group-placeholder"></label>
                  <input id="firstname" type="text" v-model="details.firstname" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label for="lastname" class="form-group-placeholder"></label>
                  <input id="lastname" type="text" v-model="details.lastname" />
              </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label for="email" class="form-group-placeholder"></label>
                  <input id="email" type="email" v-model="details.email" />
              </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label for="password" class="form-group-placeholder"></label>
                  <input id="password" type="password" v-model="details.password" />
              </div>

<div class="col-md-12">
                <button class="btn" @click="registerUser">
                  Create an account
                </button>
              </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Register",
  data() {
    return {
      details: {
        firstname: null,
        lastname: null,
        email: null,
        password: null
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async registerUser() {
      try {
        let response = await this.$axios.post(
          "/register",
          this.details
        );
        
      } catch (error) {
        
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Test

```
import {  shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Register from "../register";

describe("RegisterSponsor", () => {

  it("Will trigger an action with default object when form is submited", async () => {
    const expectedData = {
      firstname: null,
      lastname: null,
      email: null,
      password: null
    };
    const RegisterUser = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Register, {
      data() {
        return {
          details: {
            expectedData
          }
        };
      },
methods: {
    registerUser()
}
    });
    wrapper.find("button").trigger("click");
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

    expect(RegisterUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I get several errors here like 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined' and `[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined"` 
The submit trigger also does not work. The docs could be better to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you mount the component there is no need to pass `data` and `methods` argument, `data()` of your component will be set automatically and you will be using existing `methods` of your component. Second, if you want to assert that `registerUser` was called, you should spy on that method like that:

```
jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'registerUser')
```

And the third, if you are not checking DOM-structure of your component after clicking the button, you can get rid of `$nextTick` call.

Summing up the above, the test should look like that:

```
describe("RegisterSponsor", () => {

  it('Will trigger an action with default object when form is submited', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Register);
    jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'registerUser')
    await wrapper.find('button').trigger('click');
    expect(wrapper.vm.registerUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Eduardo, however i still get some errors, 
1. 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined'
2. Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

Comment: How are you trying to access ```firstname```?

Comment: await wrapper.setData({ details: {
      firstname: 'james',
    }
   })
doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to achieve. But if you want to set input's value you should use ```setValue``` method like it's said in [docs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setvalue)